# Can some one tell me a way to find the native implementations of java methods?

Tags: java, java-6

Can some one tell me a way to find the native implementations of java methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the complete source for openjdk including the (c/c++) implementations of the native methods here: http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/

(There are bundles for jdk 7 and jdk 8 too)

Answer (score 1):

Native implementation of java function are done in JNI. If you have a class call org.abc.MyClass.java, its JNI implementation fora ny native function wil be in a file like org_abc_MyClass.c.

Answer (score 0):

Dowload the jdk(link posted in previous answer) then use locate(to search name) and ack(a grep replacement to find stuff located inside the files, ex. ack --java "regex")